# Como puedo crear un diccionario de este tipo en python django

Tags: python, django, diccionarios, python-requests, hash

Tengo una consulta de eventos,
{'evento_id','nombre',....}
y otros datos donde estan las calificaciones de los eventos
{'id_calificacion','evento_id','usuario_id','valor_calificacion'......]

```
eventos={'evento_id','nombre',....},{'evento_id','nombre',....},{'evento_id','nombre',....}
calificaciones={'id_calificacion','evento_id','usuario_id','valor_calificacion'......},{'id_calificacion','evento_id','usuario_id','valor_calificacion'......],

for evento in eventos:
    for calificacion in calificaciones:
        #Pregunto si el evento id = calificacion_evento_id y que el usuario que esta en sesion es el que califico 
        if evento.id == calificacion['evento_id'] and calificacion['user_id'] == request.user.id:
            calificados['usuario']=request.user.id
            calificados['eventos_calificados']=  [calificacion['evento_id'],]
```

si imprimo el resultado de calificados
obtengo

```
{ 'usuario': 1, 'eventos_calificados': [1]}
```

y deberia de haber otro evento en eventos calificados ya que hay 2 eventos en base de datos pero no lo guarda si no que sustituye lo que debería de ser un array de eventos
el resultado esperado es
califico

```
{'usuario': 1,'eventos_calificados': [1,2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada se supone que aquí debería dar error:

```
if evento.id == calificacion['evento_id'] ...
```

Porque se supone que **estas iterando diccionarios no objetos**:

```
eventos={'evento_id','nombre',....},{'evento_id','nombre',....},{'evento_id','nombre',....}
for evento in eventos:
    ...
```

**...**

Por otra parte la razón del porque no obtienes el resultado esperado, es que en cada iteracion estas sobrescribiendo el valor de la key `eventos_calificados`.

Entonces si el diccionario `calificados` **ya tiene la key `eventos_calificados` con el valor de una lista**, entonces simplemente tienes que agregar elementos a la lista:

```
...
calificados['eventos_calificados'].append(calificacion['evento_id'])
```

En caso contrario, es decir que no exista la key `eventos_calificados` en el diccionario `calificados` (que lo dudo), la creamos:

```
for evento in eventos:
    for calificacion in calificaciones:
        if evento.id == calificacion['evento_id'] and calificacion['user_id'] == request.user.id:
            calificados['usuario']=request.user.id

            if not calificados.get('eventos_calificados'):
                calificados['eventos_calificados'] = [calificacion['evento_id']]
            else:
                calificados['eventos_calificados'].append(calificacion['evento_id'])
```

Y listo, deberías obtener el resultado deseado... pero tu código no debería funcionar, como lo dije anteriormente...

Espero haberte ayudado.